# Заменить тег br на p

Tags: php

Можно ли как-то средствами PHP при считывании текста заменить все теги `<br>` на `<p></p>`?

Comment: `str_replace`. Только наверное `<br>` лучше заменить на `</p><p>`

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так

```
function replace_br($data) {
    $data = preg_replace('#(?:<br\s*/?>\s*?){1,}#', '</p><p>', $data);
    return "<p>$data</p>";
}
```

Вариант №2 (от Visman)

```
function replace_br($data) {
    $data = preg_replace('#(?:<br\s*/?>\s*?)+#', '</p><p>', $data);
    return "<p>$data</p>";
}
```

Comment: Два и больше `<br>` (`{2,}`) на одну пару `</p><p>`?

Comment: можно и так, просто подумал легче убрать чем добавить

Comment: Ваше регулярное выражение не соответствует одиночному тегу `<br>`. Пруф: https://ideone.com/45rBAr

Comment: @DmitriySimushev спасибо большое, исправил

Comment: `{1,}` это `+`.