# Замена перевода строки на хтмл тег p в wysibb editor

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Заменяю перевод строки на `</p><p>` как показано [в этом решении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/455519/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3-br-%D0%BD%D0%B0-p), но возникает проблема, если в тексте появляются теги `<h2></h2>`, например.
После замены теги заголовков оказываются внутри тегов `<p>`, что не есть правильно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как преобразовать строку перед заменой, чтобы теги заголовков (не нумерованных списков) не попадали внутрь тегов `<p>`

Comment: Для перевода строки всю жизнь использовался тег <br/>

Comment: @rjhdby, понятное дело, но как же заключить текст в абзацы?

Comment: Колхозные решениея какие-то у вас. Берете и разбиваете текст по переносу строки в массив, потом каждый элемент массива оборачиваете в параграф и клеите массив (implode) по разделителю <br />.

Comment: @ilyaplot, почему наличие `<br/>` между параграфами делает решение менее колхозным?

Comment: В общем случае без парсера html эту проблему не решить

Comment: @vp_arth Я совершенно не думал о `p` с `br`, когда писал комментарий. Конечно, `br` уже не нужен в варианте с параграфами. Колхозно заменять `\n` на `</p><p>`

Comment: @vp_arth http://htmlpurifier.org/ отлично подойдет

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php :)

Comment: @E_p, заменяю на теги абзацев, зачем мне br? С абзацами наглядней, семантичней и управлять отображением проще.

Answer (score -1):

Присоединюсь к комментарию выше:

Используй тег `<span>` и переноси их по `<br>`, иначе в конце строки вставляй разрыв с помощью `\n` через php